# Vote once per post in Angular app

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Right now a user can only vote up or down once in general. I want a user to be able to vote up or down once per post.

```
<div ng-repeat="post in posts | orderBy:'-upvotes'">

    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"
      ng-click="incrementUpvotes(post)" ng-style="post.hadUpvoted ? {color: 'red'} : {}"></span>
    {{post.upvotes}}

    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-down" ng-click="downvote(post)" 
      ng-style="post.hadDownvoted ? {color:'red'} : {}"></span>
```

Controller:

```
var upvoted;
$scope.incrementUpvotes = function(post) {
    if(!upvoted) {
        posts.upvote(post);
        upvoted = true; 
        post.hadUpvoted = true; 
    }
};
```

Service:

```
o.upvoteComment = function(post, comment) {
    return $http.put('/posts/' + post._id + '/comments/' + comment._id + '/upvote', null, {
        headers: {Authorization: 'Bearer '+auth.getToken()}
        }).success(function(data) {
            comment.upvotes += 1; 
        });
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of checking global `upvoted` variable, check it against each post.

Your controller should be something like this,

```
$scope.incrementUpvotes = function(post) {
    if(!post.hadUpvoted) {
        posts.upvote(post);
        post.hadUpvoted = true; 
    }
};
```

The idea is to have `upvoted` variable locally for each post.

Hope it helps. If any doubt ask in comments.

Answer (score 0):

`upvoted` is scoped to the entire controllers, so when you check `if(!upvoted)`, if the user has voted once, that block will not run. Check instead `if(!post.hadUpvoted)` as that is scoped to each post.